# Want to remove warning without change data-type to char

Tags: c, scanf, compiler-warnings

I want to remove warning without change data-type to char.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    unsigned char ch;
    printf("Hello This is Problematic\n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    printf("1\n");
}
```

This generates the warning

> test.c:7:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned char *’ [-Wformat=]   scanf("%d",&ch);

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This is a warning about a serious bug in your program. The entire behavior of your program is undefined.

Comment: `%d` --> `"%hhu"` or `%c`, `main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: scanf to int, then check length and copy to char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually,

```
scanf("%d",&ch);
```

leaves your program with [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as the supplied argument is not the correct type for the conversion specifier. You need to write

```
scanf("%hhu",&ch);
```

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2

> `hh`
>
> Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, or `n` conversion specifier applies
>   to an argument with type pointer to `signed char` or `unsigned char`.